# What is the relationship between Fourier transformation and Fourier series?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Is there any connection between Fourier transformation of a function and its Fourier series of the function? I only know the formula to find Fourier transformation and to find Fourier coefficients to find the corresponding Fourier series.

Comment: Series is on an interval of fixed length, function required periodic...That being said, one proof that the transform does what it says is by the series. Tons of detail. If you are self studying, what books do you have?

Comment: All the answers are good. But I have to collect more information and study more to understand them.

Comment: @WillJagy I have seen one chapter on Fourier Series from the "Introductory Functional Analysis with Application" by "E. Kreyszig" and one chapter on Fourier Series from "Linear Partial Differential Equation for Scientists and Engineer" by "Tyn Myint-U & Lokenath Debnath". My study on Fourier analysis is at very preliminary level.

Comment: This seems promising. http://maa-store.hostedbywebstore.com/FOURIER-SERIES-Rajendra/dp/0883857405?class=quickView&field_availability=-1&field_browse=2673527011&id=FOURIER+SERIES+Rajendra&ie=UTF8&refinementHistory=brandtextbin%2Csubjectbin%2Ccolor_map%2Cprice%2Csize_name&searchNodeID=2673527011&searchPage=2&searchRank=salesrank&searchSize=12

Comment: Meanwhile, a few years ago I found several mathematics societies in India, some regional. You could join one or two. You could also join the MAA, who concentrate on college level material.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for suggestions. I have collected a soft copy of this book just now. I have visited two websites of mathematical societies. I did not know about them. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

Given a locally compact abelian group $G$, one can define the **character group** of $G$ as the group of continuous homomorphisms $G \to S^1$. (It should actually land in $\mathbf C^\times$, but for the purpose at hand, this is good enough.)

The character group of the circle $S^1$ is isomorphic with $\mathbf Z$ (the characters are $\chi_n : \theta \mapsto e^{2\pi i n\theta}$).

On the other hand, the character group of $\mathbf R$ is isomorphic with $\mathbf R$ itself. The characters are $\chi_t : s \mapsto e^{2\pi i st}$.

It is a general principle that the characters of a locally compact group form a "basis" for the space of "nice-enough" functions on the group. Thus, periodic functions (i.e. functions on the circle) have a decomposition as sums of $e^{2\pi i n\theta}$ (Fourier series), whereas functions on $\mathbf R$ have a decomposition as Fourier integrals (inverse Fourier transform of their Fourier transform).

I'm sweeping hundreds of years of analysis under the rug (not that I know all of it), but this is the general idea.

Comment: This seems pretty abstract for the average person just learning FS and FT. (Still a good answer though)

Comment: +1, nice answer. However, given how the question was formulated, it could be more appropriate to simply say that Fourier transform is recovered from Fourier series when their period goes to infinity.

Answer (score 11):

One can (at least on an informal level) think of Fourier transforms as a kind of limit of Fourier series.

If $f$ is a function on $\mathbb R$, we can restrict it to the interval $[N,-N]$,
where it has a Fourier series, namely

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n  e^{\frac{\pi i n x}{N}} ,$$

where $$a_n = \frac{1}{2N}\int_{-N}^N f(x) e^{\frac{-\pi i n x}{N}}dx
= \frac{1}{2N}\int_{-N}^N  f(x)e^{-ix y} dx,$$ where $y = \pi n/N$.

This is valid for $x \in [-N,N].$

So $$f(x) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{ixy} \cdot \int_{-N}^N
f(x) e^{-ixy} dx \cdot \frac{\Delta y}{2\pi},$$ where $y = \pi n/N$, and $\Delta y = \pi/N$
(again, valid for $x \in [-N,N]$).

Letting $N \to \infty$, defining $$\hat{f}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f(x)e^{-ixy} dy,$$ and thinking of the sum as a Riemann sum, we find that
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}  
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(y)e^{ixy} dy,$$
now valid for all $x \in (-\infty,\infty).$

This is the representation of $f$ as the integral of its Fourier transform.

(The above is informal, since I didn't carefully discuss convergence issues.  It is a very traditional and well-known intuition, though, and can be made rigorous in various contexts; e.g. my memory is that Wiener proved his Tauberian theorem by passing from the Fourier series to the Fourier transform context using this sort of argument.)

Answer (score 7):

I like to think of both Fourier series and Fourier transforms as decomposing functions against spectral measures on $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively.

A Fourier series takes a function $f$ on $\mathbb{S}^1$ and decomposes it as a sum of projections onto eigenspaces. Writing $e^{i\lambda x} = e_\lambda(x)$ and the $L^2$ inner product as $(\cdot |\cdot )$, 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{\pm\lambda\in2\pi\mathbb{Z}} \bigg( \int f(\xi)e^{-i\lambda\xi}d\xi \bigg)e_\lambda(x) = \sum_{\pm\lambda\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}}(f|e_\lambda)e_\lambda. $$
Here, $\lambda$ ranges over the spectrum of the Laplace operator. For each $\lambda$ in the spectrum, $f$ is projected onto the eigenspace (spanned by $e_{\pm\lambda}(x)$). The original function $f$ is recovered by summing over all projections.

The same idea illustrates the Fourier transform. The inversion formula indicates
$$ f(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} \hat{f}(\lambda) e^{i\langle x,\lambda\rangle}\ d\lambda = \int_\mathbb{R} \bigg( \int_\mathbb{R} f(y)e^{-i\langle \lambda,y\rangle}\ dy \bigg)e_\lambda(x)\ d\lambda\ ``=" \int_\mathbb{R} (f|e_\lambda) e_\lambda(x) d\lambda$$
Morally, the Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ evaluated at a single frequency $\lambda$ is the projection of $f$ onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace of the Laplace operator in an appropriate function space. The Fourier inversion formula indicates how one recovers the original function by "summing" (integrating) over all the projections of $f$ onto all the eigenspaces.

The general theory here is that of the *spectral measure*. A spectral measure is useful (aside from having an unbearably awesome name) because it provides a formal unifying framework for studying this kind of decomposition associated to operators on Hilbert spaces. It's a measure on $\mathbb{C}$ which takes values not in the extended complex plane, but in projections on a Hilbert space $H$: $\mu$ takes a Borel set $\sigma\subset\mathbb{C}$ and maps it to an orthogonal projection $\mu(\sigma):H\to H$. In our examples, the projections map a function to the integral of its projections onto each $\lambda$ eigenspace, for each $\lambda\in \sigma$.

Now we see that this perspective unifies both Fourier series and Fourier transforms: both are given by spectral measures associated to the Laplace operator on the spaces $\mathbb{S}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The spectrum of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{S}^1$ is discrete, so the integral is a sum of projections; the spectrum of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so the integral is an actual integral of projections.

There's some subtle analysis I'm leaving out of this -- questions of convergence, inner products, and so on. I learned (am learning) about spectral measures from Reed & Simon, *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics* (book 1). Rudin in *Functional Analysis* (ch 12, 13) calls this a "spectral decomposition." I have not checked, but would be surprised to learn the topic is not covered in Taylor's magnum opus *Partial Differential Equations*.

Comment: This seems pretty abstract for someone just learning FS and FT.

Answer (score 2):

The series and the transform are related. The series occurs when we transform a periodic signal.

Informally speaking, the transform of a periodic function looks like a comb and the spikes in that comb correspond to the terms of the series.

The transforms of nonperiodic functions are not like this. They contain a continuum of frequencies, not just discrete multiples.